# How does routing takes place in AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, network-programming

ex: ec2-203-0-113-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com

ex: url marked in this pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKcP1.png

How does the routing takes place in AWS services ?
According to url they seem to use routing according to subdomain but registering a subdomain needs 24 hours to propagate through dns servers , so how aws is handling this ?

A user just asks for a ec2 instance and aws gives those public url (not talking about public ip) instantly, they may be routing all * subdomain queries to a particular server and routes requests from there, am I correct ?

Even is the case is like above how to route further into network ? any software of hardware need to be studied here ?

And aws may be having several levels of subnets for internal network , any tool to manage or need to be studied here ?

How ec2-203-0-113-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com is helping to reach exact server ip ?

Answer (score 1):

DNS change need time because of the premise that layers between you and the DNS caches the DNS response, that can be as long as 24hr or more even. So, when you *update the domain name to another IP*, It is possible that you need to wait for hours

However, you see at the domain `ec2-203-0-113-25.compute-1.amazonaws.com` , the part `203-0-113-25` is actually it's public IP address and it does not change. As soon as you change your public IP address, your public DNS is switched to the same pattern also.

Therefore, there is *no need to update any public DNS record that can be cached by all the layer inbetween*

Comment: They may be routing according to sub domain part.

Comment: For public DNS record they might have redirected all subdomain traffic to a different server . for Ex: *.amazonaws.com in DNS record will take all requests to a particular server and routing takes place in internal network may be with help of some service of private DNS but I am not sure. Any software that can help to route this in internal network ?